# Instalação Emulador para Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.14393) - Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, emulador

Estou tentando instalar o kit de desenvolvimento mobile mas está dando esse erro em todos os itens que tentei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso para qualquer item opcional. O VS já está instalado e o meu Windows é o Windows 10 Education 64-bit.

Tentei uma instalação offline do VS .iso de 7,9 Gb em uma nova instalação do Windows mas da o mesmo erro conforme abaixo. Dessa vez com o Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma possível solução: [Visual studio 2015 RTM : windows 10 sdk 10.0.10240 The installer failed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/643464f5-5b41-4d98-8d60-3216ee09c1f5/visual-studio-2015-rtm-windows-10-sdk-10010240-the-installer-failed-the-hash-value-is-not?forum=vssetup)

Comment: Tentei essa solução e não funcionou..